# AWS CloudWatch is generating false Alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

[image]

Requirement: Generate Alarm if cpu utilization is above or equal to 85 for consecutive 4 minutes.
Problem: Alarm state changes to ALARM immediately after reaching the threshold without waiting for 4 min.

Comment: Do you have detailed monitoring enabled on that instance? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch-new.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually the period mentioned for graphs is the aggregation level, not reporting frequency.

So it's possible that you are getting one data point every 15 secs, and when you graph them, it aggregates 4 values and plots/shows you one value for minute.

In that case you should set your alarm trigger to 16 data points (each reported every 15 secs) if you want alarm to trigger after 4 minutes.

Comment: It invoked after 1 minute and when I test it again after that it is gain invoking immediately . can you suggest some other solution please

Comment: can please explain a little bit what do you mean by reporting frequency?